# Assinatura Digital PHP

Tags: php, pdf, certificado-digital, assinatura

Estou tentando realizar a assinatura digital de um documento em PHP através de certificado A1.

```
$pdf = new \FPDI();

$pdf_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\\files\\" . md5(uniqid("")) . ".pdf";
$path_assinado = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\\files\\" . md5(uniqid("")) . ".pdf";

file_put_contents($pdf_path, $pdfDocument);

$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($pdf_path);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++) {
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $page = $pdf->importPage($i);
  $pdf->useTemplate($page, 0, 0);
}

$info = [
  'Name'        => $certificado->getCompanyName(),
  'Date'    => date("Y.m.d H:i:s"),
  'Reason'      => 'Assinatura',
  'ContactInfo' => 'contact',
];
$pdf->setSignature($certificado->__toString(), $certificado->privateKey, $senha, '', 1, $info);

$pdf->Output($path_assinado, "F");

return file_get_contents($path_assinado);
```

Estou conseguindo realizar a assinatura normalmente, porém preciso enviar o arquivo assinado para o TJRJ, e a assinatura que o TCPDF está realizando, bloqueia completamente o PDF, impossibilitando edições.

Quando envio o arquivo, recebo o seguinte retorno:

> É necessário que documento informado seja possível sofrer alteração.

Tentei de várias formas resolver o problema sozinho e até o momento não consegui, alguém pode dar alguma ajuda?

PS. Já tentei mudar o valor do setSignature para 2, 3, mas o arquivo continua bloqueado.

Answer (score 4):

Consegui resolver o problema, solução:

```
private function assinarPdf($pdfDocument, Certificate $certificado, $senha) {
    $pdf = new \FPDI();

    $pdf_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\\files\\" . md5(uniqid("")) . ".pdf";
    $path_assinado = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\\files\\" . md5(uniqid("")) . ".pdf";

    file_put_contents($pdf_path, $pdfDocument);

    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($pdf_path);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++) {
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $page = $pdf->importPage($i);
        $pdf->useTemplate($page, 0, 0);
    }

    $info = [
        'Name'        => $certificado->getCompanyName(),
        'Date'        => date("Y.m.d H:i:s"),
        'Reason'      => 'Assinatura',
        'ContactInfo' => 'contact',
    ];

    $pdf->setSignature($certificado->__toString(), $certificado->privateKey, $senha, '', 2, $info, "A");
    $pdf->Output($path_assinado, "F");

    return file_get_contents($path_assinado);
}
```

Ao adicionar o campo Approval com a string "A", a assinatura vai ser realizada da forma necessária.